# Example of convergent sequence and discontinuous function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity

I need a counter example to show the following statement is false:

A function $f$ is continuous at a point c if there exists a sequence $x_n$ such that $x_n \rightarrow c$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ and $f(x_n) \rightarrow f(c)$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

I have tried $f(x) = x$ if $x\lt 0$ and $f(x) = x+1 $ if $x\ge 0$ and $x_n = \frac{1}{n}$ but it is not working.
I am having problem when I am trying to make $f(x_n) \rightarrow f(c)$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. I couldn't find a sequence such that $f(x_n)$ converges to $ f(c)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function 
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}
0 & \text{if }x<0\\
1 & \text{if }x\geq0
\end{cases}
$$
is discontinuous at $c=0$. Consider the sequence $(x_{n})_{n}$ with $x_{n}=1/n$. Clearly, $x_{n}\rightarrow c$,
and $f(x_{n})\rightarrow  f(c) = 1$.